# Realtime (RTP) Audio-Stream using WindowsPhone 8 Application

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, rtp, pcm

i am streaming an RTP Audio-Stream via an Barix InStreamer 100 with the Format:

PCM 16Bit 8kHz Mono (Little endian)

I am trying to Play that stream in "realtime" via an MediaElement using a custom MediaStreamSource. The Problem is that i'm getting an Delay of 2 seconds while playing that stream. With VLC on my PC there is "no" delay.

I found out, that MediaStreamSource has a property "AudioBufferLength" witch can be set to a value between 15ms and 1000ms. But when the value is too small, i got an exception in GetSampleAsync->ReportGetSampleCompleted

Thats my code:

```
        protected override void GetSampleAsync(MediaStreamType mediaStreamType)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("GetSampleAsync called.");

        // Start with one second of data, rounded up to the nearest block.
        var blocksize = (uint)AlignUp(_wavParser.WaveFormatEx.AvgBytesPerSec, _wavParser.WaveFormatEx.BlockAlign);

        var chunkSize = Math.Min(blocksize, (uint)_stream.Length - _currentPosition);
        var chunkDuration = _currentPosition * 10000000L / 8000;  //// _wavParser.WaveFormatEx.AudioDurationFromBufferSize((uint)chunkSize);

        // Send out the next sample
        var chunkSample = new MediaStreamSample(_mediaStreamDescription, _stream, _currentPosition, chunkSize, _currentTimeStamp, chunkDuration, _emptySampleDict);

        // Move our timestamp and position forward

        _currentPosition += chunkSize;
        _currentTimeStamp += chunkDuration;

        ReportGetSampleCompleted(chunkSample);  // <-- There i got a NullRef Ex, when the chunk is too small
    }
```

here is how i initialy open the media:

```
        protected override void OpenMediaAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a parser
            _wavParser = new WavParser(_stream);

            // Parse the header
            _wavParser.ParseWaveHeader();
            _wavParser.WaveFormatEx.ValidateWaveFormat();
            _startPosition = _currentPosition = _wavParser.DataPosition;

            // Init
            _streamAttributes = new Dictionary<MediaStreamAttributeKeys, string>();
            _sourceAttributes = new Dictionary<MediaSourceAttributesKeys, string>();
            var availableStreams = new List<MediaStreamDescription>();

            // Stream Description
            _streamAttributes[MediaStreamAttributeKeys.CodecPrivateData] = _wavParser.WaveFormatEx.ToHexString();
            _mediaStreamDescription = new MediaStreamDescription(MediaStreamType.Audio, _streamAttributes);
            availableStreams.Add(_mediaStreamDescription);

            _sourceAttributes[MediaSourceAttributesKeys.Duration] = _wavParser.Duration.ToString();
            ReportOpenMediaCompleted(_sourceAttributes, availableStreams);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error while opening media source." + exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

Can someone give me a hint? Or are there better ways to Play an RTP/PCM Stream in Realtime on an WindowsPhone (8)?  Please save my ass :)